# Customizing MVC ASP.NET Identity 2.0 without DbContext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, customization, asp.net-identity

I have a MVC 5.0 application that use WCF services and I don't have DbContext in UI layer. But in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 we have to have DbContext.
Is it possible to Customize ASP.NET Identity 2.0 to use some our services instead of DbContext ?

Comment: Checking [Implementing ASP.NET Identity by Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx) may help you

Comment: Good question. I did struggle with the same issue and at the end gave up. For Identity I had to add EF and DbContext in all my projects in the solution. I found no good way to avoid adding EF to my UI layer -(

Answer (score 1):

The one way of doing this will be following.

You have to create a `customclass` and define the properties that hold the data from your WCF service and inherit this class from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

From here you can use property getters to fetch the data from WCF Services.

 below is the sample code. It's not tested but that might help you.

```
public class CustomClass : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private DbSet<Users1> wcfDataHolder;

    public DbSet<Users1> WcfDataHolder
    {
        get
        {
            // Write your WCF code here
            // wcfDataHolder = dataFromService
            return wcfDataHolder;
        }
        set { wcfDataHolder = value; }
    }
}
```

**Two points here should be noticed.**

1. Should we be using static create function in that class that will return the instance of your `customClass`?
2. Should we pass any database connection to the base class?

**Answers**

1. As per my little knowledge you should not use the create method because creating instance is not your requirement as far as i understand.
2. Passing connection thing will not break something but that will not be the optimum solution but not passing will use the default connection string in your web.config. So i would suggest not to pass it.